# How to transfer or copy tables of DB2 to oracle database

Tags: db2, oracle11g

I want to transfer some tables of DB2 to oracle daily for accessing them from web page, 
But I don't know commands of DB2. How to do this?
I want this action should perform on database daily on particular time, so is there any tool is available to do this operation. And for writing the program for operating above query which programming language should I use? I am using windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

I think Change Data Capture is used to replicate DML from one database to other databases continuously.
However, what you need is to transfer some data at a particular time each day, thus CDC could be too heavy for that.

You could do a simply "db2 export", and then you could import the generated file from Oracle.
There should be an option to create an adapter in Oracle that permits to query DB2 tables. The opposite is called federation in DB2 (InfoSphere Information Server) that permits to query Oracle tables.

Export http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008303.html

CMD examples http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0004567.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this link
http://blogs.oracle.com/warehousebuilder/entry/simple_change_data_capture_from_db2_table_to_oracle_table

In 11.2 releases, Change Data Capture (CDC) can be done by code template mapping. This allows users to capture the data changes from heterogeneous data source, and load into the target across different platforms.